# Giving a database level trigger full access to a different database table [T-SQL]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ddl

I'm trying to have a trigger set up in an arbitrary database that will store information in a specific database on execution. However, I found that if the trigger is triggered by someone without explicit access to that database, the trigger execution will fail.

I was hoping to find away around this using:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [myTrigger] 
on database
with execute as 'UserWithPermissions'
```

but that doesn't seem to work either... Does anyone know if this is possible? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's usually a *bad* idea to have any trigger access *any* resources outside of its own database. Databases are the unit of recovery/availability in SQL Server - do you really want the unavailability of this second database (at any time) to prevent the original transaction from committing? It's usually better to use something (a queue table and agent job, or Service Broker) to detach the external activity from the original transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MSSQL Management go to DB-name => Security => Users and make sure the user has access. Also, Windows Network Authentication helps a lot when running procs from other machines

-- edit --

I think what you want is called 'EXECUTE AS'.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Demo
WITH EXECUTE AS 'SqlUser1'
AS
SELECT user_name(); -- Shows execution context is set to SqlUser1.
EXECUTE AS CALLER;
SELECT user_name(); -- Shows execution context is set to SqlUser2, the caller of the    module.
REVERT;
SELECT user_name(); -- Shows execution context is set to SqlUser1.
GO
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more please? I _did_ reference Execute As in my post but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: In MSSQL Management go to *DB-name* => Security => Users and make sure the user has access. Also, Windows Network Authentication helps a lot when running procs from other machines.

Comment: That's the problem... Everytime I create this trigger on a database, will I have to ensure there is a user created that has access to the one the trigger will insert into?

Ideally, I would always want the trigger to have access to its target, without needing to manipulate a user to do so.

Comment: You can set permisions by group, user, network, and even machine name with some licenses I believe. I would recommend setting up Window Network Auth, and then only allow connections from maybe a 10.*.*.* range (class-a 10.* ip's will never be internet routable).